# How do I select mothers in the table that have children of all the listed genders? (implementing RA Division in SQL)

Tags: sql

I have a table (person) with the following columns:
*name, gender, mother*

and I need to extract the names of the mothers who have a baby of every gender. I'm not allowed to assume that gender is limited to just M and F.

I can do `SELECT DISTINCT person.gender FROM person` to get a list of all genders present in the table.

I also created a table with all the names of the mothers and their child's gender as the two columns.

The problem is, I have no idea how to check if a mother has had a child of all respective genders in the table. How can I implement this?

Edit: How I achieved my final solution can be found below, thank you all for your answers! I have also updated the title to help others find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I implemented the relational algebra division method into SQL using various `EXCEPT` and `IN` conditions. Relational algebra division works great when you have two columns, where some kind of label (e.g. a name) is connected to some type (e.g. gender), and you wish to find if a specific label is linked to all types that are specified in another, separate table.

In my case the list of labels were the names of the mothers, and their associated type was the gender of their child. Using the `SELECT` statement I created in my question post, this gave me a list of genders where each mother must have for my query. This was my "type" table, that all the mothers had to link to.

This is how I got the answer to my question in the end.

A nice, detailed guide on how to implement it is here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-division/

The other answers do also work and are much simpler, but this solution feels more general and I think it should be shared!

Answer (score 1):

Group the mothers' records together, and in each group count how many distinct genders there are.

```
SELECT
  mother
FROM
  person
GROUP BY
  mother
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT gender) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT gender) FROM person)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately approached the issue the same as @MatBailie but found it useful to include the COUNT in the final query as well. You basically need two things to make this type of query work. 1) A collection of distinct mothers, 2) The number of distinct genders. A GROUP BY and an aggregate subquery works nicely here.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT gender) AS genderCount, mother FROM person
GROUP BY mother
HAVING genderCount = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT gender) from person);
```